# Python: Scipy: brute optimization

Tags: python, scipy

I am getting this error

> TypeError: objfunc() missing 1 required positional argument: 'q'

when I try to brute optimize the objective function.

What I am doing wrong?

```
def objfunc(p,q):
    return p**3-2**q;

from scipy.optimize import brute
grid = (slice(1, 300, 1),slice(1, 300, 1))
solution = brute(objfunc, grid, finish=None,full_output = True)
`enter code here`*TypeError: objfunc() missing 1 required positional argument: 'q'*'''
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to correct the objfunc. Also the range for `q` is very high , you may change it to prevent overflows

```
def objfunc(grid):
    p, q = grid
    return p**3-2**q;

grid = (slice(1, 300, 1),slice(1, 30, 1))
```